# API to retrieve answers for general questions

Tags: gratis, api, nlp, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I was looking for a service (with API) where I can ask it a general question (aka, when was Einstein born?) and retrieve an answer from the Web.

Is there any available service to do that? Have tried Watson services but didn't work as expected.

Thanks,

Comment: OK if it supports only English? What is your budget and volume?

Comment: Yup it's okay, I need for a small experiment

Comment: Please add this information into your question (edit it), comments get deleted. Thanks!

Comment: What is *didn't work as expected*? What output format do you want, JSON? Please [edit] your question

Answer (score 1):

There is [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

This is essentially a search engine with significant internal intelligence.

It has an [API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/developers/) and can be embedded in web pages.  Its output can be textual or graphical.

Furthermore, there are [apps for phones & tablets](http://products.wolframalpha.com/mobile/) to interact with the knowledge base.

You have tagged your question [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis).  The API is free for "personal and experimental" use, if you wish to make extensive and/or commercial use you will have to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following services:

- [IBM Watson services](https://developer.ibm.com/watson/) (see: [API docs](https://developer.ibm.com/watson/)).
- [Amazon Alexa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Alexa) and [Alexa Skills Kit](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa).

  > The Alexa Skills Kit is a collection of self-service APIs, tools, documentation and code samples that make it fast and easy for you to add skills to Alexa.

  See the demo at [echosim.io](https://echosim.io/).